# Integral with set in the differential

Tags: integration, notation

I encountered several integrals by now that integrate over a "set of differentials" or is with respect to a set respectively, like the (physicist) partition function of a polymer with varying segment length
$$Z=\int_P \mathrm{d}\{\ell\}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\beta \mathcal{H}(\{\ell\})}\quad\left(=\int_{L_1} \mathrm{d}\ell_1\int_{L_2} \mathrm{d}\ell_2\dotsi\int_{L_N} \mathrm{d}\ell_N\,\mathrm{e}^{-\beta\mathcal{H}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\dots,\ell_N)}\right)$$
or the multivariate marginal distribution
$$P(\{X_i=x_i\}_{0\leq i\leq m})=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n-m}}\mathrm{d}\{x_j\}_{m<j\leq n}\,P(\{X_i=x_i\}_{0\leq i\leq n})$$
standing for
$$P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_m=x_m)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_{m+1}\dotsi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_{n}\,P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_m=x_m,\dots,X_n=x_n).$$
Is this a common notation or generally understood, or is it a more special notation of e.g. physicists. I can see that this is probably (from a mathematicians side) not very rigorous but merely a notational convention.

Comment: Everything is good except for the $\mathrm{d}\{x_j\}_{m\leq j\leq n}$ which looks like a set in the middle of an integral which makes no sense. A better way of writing this would simply be $\mathrm{d}x_m\dots \mathrm{d}x_n$ or if you wanted to get fancy
$$\prod_{j=m}^n \mathrm{d}x_j$$ **EDIT:** And I assume you want to integrate over $\mathbb{R}^n$, not just $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Although this is the point, I see where they're getting the idea for this notation basically $\mathrm{d}\{x_j\}_{m<j\leq n}$ is short for $\mathrm{d}\{x_{m+1},\dots,x_n\}$ in the sense of integrating with respect to each element of the set. Another occasion I saw this type of notation was in DNA binding optimization where we have the sum $$Z=\sum_{\{S\}}\mathrm{e}^{-\beta E(\{S\})},$$where $\{S\}$ is the set of all DNA sequences relevant for the optimization. The problem is this notation doesn't seem to be "correct" or perfect, but I acknowledge the way it simplifies these kind of indices.